# Installing a new domain server on a small network without taking down the old one

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, domain, dhcp, domain-controller

I'm attempting to replace a windows server 2003 domain controller/dns/dhcp server on a small business network with a new machine running server 2012 without having to take down the old one until everything is configured.  I would like to be able to set up the server with a different domain name, add the accounts, and have the users log in over the new domain before actually enabling dhcp and dns on the new server (relying on the old one to handle this until those roles are switched as well).

The current network configuration is one server handling domain, dns, and dhcp connected to a switch that also connects to the office patch panel going to the workstations and the cable modem.

Does this approach make sense and is it reasonably possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a new domain controller is just fine.  Install, join to the domain, run `dcpromo`, follow the standard Microsoft guide for it, fine. Migrating DNS and DHCP services? Relatively easy. For all intensive porpoises, you're creating the second domain controller that you should have had in place to begin with.

You mentioned that you want to change the domain name.  That's where it gets very sticky.  Once you have a domain in place, you really don't want to be changing domain names without having a very good reason for doing so.

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781575%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on it:

> Domain rename is intended to be a supported method for renaming domains when domain renames are necessary; it is not intended to make domain rename a routine operation. The domain rename process is complex, and it requires a great deal of care in planning and execution. In addition, the time that is required for a complete domain rename operation is directly proportional to the size of an Active Directory forest in terms of its number of domains, domain controllers, and member computers. Therefore, although domain rename is possible, it should not be undertaken lightly.

If I'm misunderstanding, and you want a SECOND domain created with new user accounts and everything, while still interacting on the same network with the old one, then you're probably doing it wrong. Having two completely separate domain infrastructures interacting with the same clients and DNS server is chaos unless you're intimately familiar with everything they do.